# Fuchsia OS : Magenta Kernel: Installation on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: kernel, curl, magenta-kernel, fuchsia

I am on proxy server. Trying to install the magenta kernel using the [getting started manual](https://github.com/fuchsia-mirror/magenta/blob/master/docs/getting_started.md).

when I run this command `./scripts/download-toolchain`, I get the following error log messages:

```
sudo ./scripts/download-toolchain 
curl Downloading https://fuchsia-build.storage.googleapis.com/magenta/toolchain/x86_64-elf/Linux-x86_64/509cd48809f5252ffc8ef0c72dbf208151750f66

curl: (60) server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html 

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
using the --cacert option.

If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
not match the domain name in the URL).

If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

- Tried adding `curl --insecure` but ended up getting a `tar/bz2` error.
- Also, tried to build the tool-chains manually, but while building the kernel using this command `make -j32 magenta-pc-x86-64` returned numerous error.

Please help me to proceed further. Thank you in advance.

**Request**: Can some one please add the new tags for `fuchsia` and `magenta-kernel`, I dont have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: @dtbnguyen its "fuchsia"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working behind proxy is a real pain. Nevertheless, if you face the same problem at your workplace, make sure your proxy is configured and there are company specific (ca) certificates. Add them and update your system and things similar to this will work.  (Do not waste time building toolchains manually: things wont work and you end up investing too much time)